# Comparing Two Excel files using Hadoop Mapreduce

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, hadoop, mapreduce, emr

I am new to Hadoop and Mapreduce. I have a requirement to compare two excel files using mapreduce. I have to go to mapreduce as the size of these files will be very big(>10gb). My question is how do I get two different input files from different mapper and compare these two files in Reducer.I have to convert this application into jar and run it in Amazon EMR.I am not able to find suitable tutorial for this in web. Kindly provide me some ideas to do this.

Comment: I presume you would want to compare the excel sheet row by row. Do you have any common column in both spreadsheets that will relate rows from two spreadsheets ?

Comment: Amit, Actually I need to compare each cell in both the excel files. I could loop it. But before that i need to read to excel files and send it to reducer

Comment: Please do not rush towards mapper or reducer so soon. Does comparing each cell mean A1 in first spreadsheet compared to A1 in second ? Or A1 with all other cells in another spreadsheet ?

Comment: @Amit It is like comparing Cell A1 in first spreadsheet with Cell A1 in second spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

I think that distributed cache would be useful in your situation. I haven't used distributed cache with large files but please explore and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will try that and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your answers to my comment here is how I think it should be done if you are implementing it using plain Map-reduce -

1. Create a custom [InputFormat](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.3/api/index.html?org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/InputFormat.html) that reads the excel spreadsheet.
2. As part of this you would need [RecordReader](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.3/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/RecordReader.html) that reads Excel spreadsheet and outputs Cell location ( A1 for example) as key and its content as Value.
3. Once the files are read you need to do inner join on two datasets using Key ( which is cell location).
4. Post join, you can compare the contents of the cell.

It may be helpful if you take a look at Apache Pig or Cascading kind of APIs that abstract plain map-reduce.

Regards,
Amit